# SQL find the maximum value

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables:

**Customer table**

| CustomerId | FirstName | LastName | Country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Luís | Gonçalves | Brazil |
| 2 | Leonie | Köhler | Germany |
| 3 | François | Tremblay | Canada |
| 4 | Bjørn | Hansen | Norway |
| 52 | Emma | Jones | United Kingdom |
| 53 | Phil | Hughes | United Kingdom |

**Invoice table**

| InvoiceId | CustomerId | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1.98 |
| 2 | 4 | 3.96 |
| 3 | 8 | 5.94 |
| 140 | 52 | 23.76 |
| 369 | 52 | 13.86 |
| 283 | 53 | 28.71 |
| 109 | 53 | 8.91 |

I have to write a query that returns the country along with the top customer and how much they spent. For countries where the top amount spent is shared, provide all customers who spent this amount.

I wrote a query like:

```
SELECT c.CustomerId, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.Country, SUM(i.Total) AS TotalSpent
FROM Customer c
JOIN Invoice i
ON c.CustomerId = i.CustomerId
GROUP BY c.FirstName, c.LastName
HAVING i.Total >= MAX(i.Total)
ORDER BY c.Country;
```

the query is not finding the maximum values but it is returning all available values.
I am not sure about which DBMS is used as it is my first steps in SQL coding and above example is from Udacity learning platform lab (Maybe it is SQLite that they are using in the lab)

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please share with us database that you use ? Is it Oracle maybe ?

Comment: Could you please add some sample data and expected output? I'm not fully clear about every detail.

Comment: (Edit) 1. Thanks, though it might help to have a few more rows of sample data, to demonstrate what you mean by maximum 2. What are the expected results, using that sample data? 3. Also, which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Thanks SOS! I added a few more rows. "Maximum"  is spent total value  (Total column) of which customer is highest in every country. Also, if top total value is shared (more than one highest value) within a particular country then I have to include all of them. Here from the sample: Customers with 52 and 53 Id (Emma & Phil) from United Kingdom have spent the same amount and this is top spent amount by UK customers in the Dbase, so both have to be included. Hope this clears

Comment: @Oybek - Sorry didn't see your comment till just now. (S.O. has some confusing notification rules.  As soon as multiple people leave comments, S.O. only notifies someone there's a new reply if you use `@Their_User_Name_Here`, and you can only notify one person.) Anyway, glad you solved it. Though you forgot to say which DBMS you're using :) You can still [edit] the question tags to include your dbms. That'll help the next person searching for an answer to the same question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below code worked fine to fulfill all the requirements:

```
 WITH tab1 AS
( SELECT c.CustomerId, c.FirstName, c.LastName,c.Country, SUM(i.Total) as TotalSpent
FROM Customer AS c
JOIN Invoice i ON c.CustomerId = i.CustomerId
GROUP BY C.CustomerId
)
SELECT tab1.*
FROM tab1
JOIN
( SELECT CustomerId, FirstName, LastName, Country, MAX(TotalSpent) AS TotalSpent
FROM tab1
GROUP BY Country
)tab2
ON tab1.Country = tab2.Country
WHERE tab1.TotalSpent = tab2.TotalSpent
ORDER BY Country;
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not shared your database with us.
Also, you need to add expected results in your question from the data you provided.
But lets say you use SQLite then this would work I think:

```
select CustomerId
       , FirstName
       , LastName
       , Country
       , max(tot)
from ( select sum(i1.Total) as tot
              , i1.CustomerId
              , c1.Country
              , c1.FirstName
              , c1.LastName
       FROM Customer c1
       JOIN Invoice i1
       ON c1.CustomerId = i1.CustomerId
       group by i1.CustomerId) TAB
group by Country
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=85f0cb9052fd06ba6e1f5575739ff4c3)

After the comment from the OP I have edited the code:

```
select c.CustomerId, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.Country, sum(Total)
from Customer c
JOIN Invoice i ON c.CustomerId = i.CustomerId
group by country, c.CustomerId
having sum(Total) in (select  max(tot) as tot2
                      from (select sum(i1.Total) as tot
                                   , country
                            FROM Customer c1
                            JOIN Invoice i1
                            ON c1.CustomerId = i1.CustomerId
                            group by i1.CustomerId) TAB
                      group by country)
```

[DEMO2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=5090dc267ca62fe8600310ea7eb8469e)

Comment: VBoka, sorry for posting sample in comments as I am new here I did'nt know that. I don't know my database, this is from Udacity learning platform. Thank you, your query worked perfectly fine, just except for one criteria, that is if "top amount spent is shared i.e. there are same max amounts I have to provide all customers who spent this amount

Comment: It would fail on postgre SQL for not containing country, first and last name in the `group by` clause...

Comment: Hello @Oybek, I have added new query. Check it out.

Comment: Hello @Aconcagua that is why I have written: "lets say you use SQLite" because I know it would fail on Postgres, Oracle.... I have tested the code of the OP first and then made my opinion. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Hi VBoka, thank you for your prompt answer. Your previous query is diong the work. Only exception is that it can not handle the issue if there is more than one top amount (total) within a particular country. In my case for example, customers with 52 and 53 Id (Emma & Phil) from United Kingdom have spent the same amount and this is top spent amount by UK customers in the Dbase, so both have to be included. Your last query didn't bring top totals but just all of them. Thank you anyway, I'll try to figure out the remainig part of this.

Comment: Hello, I do not understand. Please click on the DEMO2. You can clearly see that the customer called A and customer called D both from the same country called A and both spent 600 are in the result. Also, the customer called C is there because he is from country called B... Please explain how is that not the solution for the exception you describe ?

Answer (score 0):

As the accepted (at the time of writing this answer) solution would fail on at least PostgreSQL (for not including a selected value in either the group by clause or an aggregate function) I provide another variant:

```
WITH t AS
(
    SELECT
        c.customerid AS i, c.last_name  AS l, c.first_name AS f,
        c.country    AS c, SUM(i.total) AS s
    FROM customer c JOIN invoice i ON c.customerid = i.customerid 
    GROUP BY c.customerid, c.country
    -- note: last and first name do not need to be included in the group by clause
    --       here as the (assumed!) primary key 'customerid' already is
)
SELECT c, l, f, s FROM t
WHERE s = (SELECT MAX(s) FROM t WHERE t.c = c)
```

(tested on PostgreSQL)